# Generate family of linear inequalities from vector variable for use in `FindInstance`

Tags: list-manipulation, vector, inequalities, variable

Suppose that I have a vector variable `xvec = Array[x, 10]`.
How do I generate the family of linear inequalities

$$F = \{ {x\in\mathbb{R}^{10}:x_1\geq x_2,\ldots,x_9\geq x_{10}} \}$$

```
xvec[[1]] >= xvec[[2]] ,..., xvec[[9]] >= xvec[[10]]
```

Specifically, I would like to do something like:

```
xvec = Array[x, 10]
FindInstance[xvec[[1]]>=xvec[[2]],...,xvec[[9]]>=xvec[[10]],{xvec}]
```

which is trivial now but is trying to get at a MWE.

Comment: `FindInstance[GreaterEqual @@ xvec, xvec]` gives: `{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, 
  x[7] -> 0, x[8] -> 0, x[9] -> 0, x[10] -> 0}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

```
xvec = Array[x, 10];

ineqs = Table[x[i] >= x[i + 1], {i, 1, Length[xvec] - 1}]
(* {x[1] >= x[2], x[2] >= x[3], x[3] >= x[4], x[4] >= x[5], x[5] >= x[6],
    x[6] >= x[7], x[7] >= x[8], x[8] >= x[9], x[9] >= x[10]} *)

FindInstance[ineqs, xvec]
(* {{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, 
     x[7] -> 0, x[8] -> 0, x[9] -> 0, x[10] -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! If I have another variable, say a scalar `y` that I would like to include in the `FindInstance`, how would I add this in? For example, suppose I have another inequality `ineqy = y>0` and I would like to do `FindInstance[ineqs && y > 0, {xvec, y}]` but I get an error saying `FindInstance::ivar: {x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10]} is not a valid variable.`

Comment: Not sure if this question is related enough to my original one. If not, then I can create a new question (albeit in like 15 minutes when my post-time-limit deactivates)!

Comment: @rrrrr, you seem to be a novice in Mathematica. I know it can be difficult in the beginning, but it will not be very productive or helpful if you keep asking many small question on StackExchange (yes, there is a good reason for the time-limit). Also, changing a question or adding new subquestions after you got the answer is really discouraged here. I strongly suggest you read through Mathematica tutorials for beginners. There are many of them:

Comment: I am! Ok I will remove my edits and look through the tutorial :)

Comment: (1) [Fast Introduction for Math Students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/), (2) [The Wolfram Language:
Fast Introduction for Programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/), (3) [Stephen Wolfram: An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/), and of course tens of thousands of existing questions on this StackExchange.

Answer (score 4):

In version 12, Mathematica introduced a family of vector comparisons including `\[VectorLessEqual]`. We can use `Differences` and then the above operator to get the same effect:

```
xvec = Array[x, 10]

FindInstance[Differences[xvec] \[VectorLessEqual] 0, xvec]

(* Out: {{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, 
  x[7] -> 0, x[8] -> 0, x[9] -> 0, x[10] -> 0}} *)
```

It's much nicer to see in Mathematica than code:

[image]